# MS Access - decimal column and mapping to .NET decimal value causes "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to insert .NET decimal value data into MS Access column 'decimal'

MS Access column is defined as number decimal - precision 18 scale 2

OleDbParameter is created this way:

```
                var p3 = new OleDbParameter();
                p3.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Decimal;
                p3.Value = 10.12m;
                p3.Precision = 18;
                p3.Scale = 2;
```

After executing command I receive "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" exception.

What am I doing wrong?

MS Access is 2007 but the dababase is in old file format *.mdb.

Comment: Uh, MDF is a SQL Server file, not Jet/ACE/Access. Do you mean MDB?

Comment: Yes, it's *.MDB. Thanks for notice.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding an m to your value. In C# m specifies a decimal value instead of a double.

```
            var p3 = new OleDbParameter();
            p3.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Decimal;
            p3.Value = 10.12m;//added the m here to specify the decimal value.
            p3.Precision = 18;
            p3.Scale = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

try just setting the value and see if it takes it:

```
var p3 = new OleDbParameter();
//p3.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Decimal;
p3.Value = 10.12;
//p3.Precision = 18;
//p3.Scale = 2;
```

or try setting the value to a whole number.  My guess is the problem's with either `OleDbParameter` or `System.Data.DbType.Decimal`